# How can I interactively select series to plot using widgets.SelectMultiple()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

**Background:**

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891860/interactive-selection-of-series-in-a-matplotlib-plot), but was not very specific and was mostly only answered with references to other sources. My case feels pretty basic, and I'm surprised by how hard it was to find working examples of this.

**Goal:**

I would just like to be able to select any subset from a pandas dataframe to make a plot like below by using a widget like this:

[image]

**My attempts:**

The `widgets.SelectMultiple()` widget is briefly described in the [docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#SelectMultiple), and [this section](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Flickering-and-jumping-output) describes how you can interactively change values for series in a plot. I've tried to replace the central parts of the latter demonstration with the functionalities of `widgets.SelectMultiple()`, but with little success.

I *think* I'm really close to get this working, and I *hope* all I have to do is to find out what to write under the section marked **'# what to do!?'** in the snippet below. As the snippet now stands, a widget and chart is produced, but there's no functioning link between them.

**Issues that I'm aware of:**

My reproduction of the examples provided in the links has some flaws. I think `df` and `widg` should be included in the `multiplot` function. The same goes perhaps for the `interactive plot` function. I've tried different variations of that too, but with no success.

**Snippet (used in a Jupyter Notebook):**

```
# imports
%matplotlib inline

from ipywidgets import interactive
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from jupyterthemes import jtplot

# Sample data
np.random.seed(123)
rows = 50
dfx = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(90,110,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable X'])
dfy = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(25,68,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable Y'])
dfz = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(60,70,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable Z'])

df = pd.concat([dfx,dfy,dfz], axis = 1)
#jtplot.style()

import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

def multiplot():
    opts = df.columns.values

    widg = widgets.SelectMultiple(
           options=opts,
           value=[opts[1]],
           rows=len(opts),
           description='Variables',
           disabled=False)

    display(widg)

    # what to do!? 
    df.plot()

    #attempts:
    #df[widg].plot()
    #df[widg.value[0]].plot()

interactive_plot = interactive(multiplot)
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '350px'
interactive_plot
```

**Output (flawed):**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the clear example. Unfortunately, I am not sure that SelectMultiple can be used in the way you intend.

Generally, for an interact call, you need a function that you pass arguments to. You should not need to create the widget inside the body of the function, the `interact` call should understand what type of input widget is required from the passed parameter.

See here for some examples where you specify a list of string options (https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Widget-abbreviations)

I have made some small alterations to your code to product an interact with a Dropdown selector. I suspect if you want to use a SelectMultiple rather than a Dropdown, this is beyond `interact` functionality. You might need to create the widget separately and then use `observe`.

```
# imports
%matplotlib inline

from ipywidgets import interactive
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# from jupyterthemes import jtplot

# Sample data
np.random.seed(123)
rows = 50
dfx = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(90,110,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable X'])
dfy = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(25,68,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable Y'])
dfz = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(60,70,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable Z'])

df = pd.concat([dfx,dfy,dfz], axis = 1)
#jtplot.style()

import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

def multiplot(a):
    opts = df.columns.values
    df.loc[:, a].plot()

interactive_plot = interactive(multiplot, a=['Variable X', 'Variable Y', 'Variable Z'])
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '350px'
interactive_plot
```

[image]

And here's a version using `observe`, a SelectMultiple widget and an `Output` widget:

```python
# imports
%matplotlib inline

from ipywidgets import interactive
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import clear_output
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
np.random.seed(123)
rows = 50
dfx = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(90,110,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable X'])
dfy = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(25,68,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable Y'])
dfz = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(60,70,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable Z'])

df = pd.concat([dfx,dfy,dfz], axis = 1)
#jtplot.style()

import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

opts = df.columns.values

selector = widgets.SelectMultiple(
options=opts,
value=[opts[1]],
rows=len(opts),
description='Variables',
disabled=False)

output = widgets.Output()

display(selector)
display(output)

def multiplot(widg):
    choices = widg['new']
    data = df.loc[:, choices] if choices else df
    output.clear_output(wait=True)
    with output:
        ax = data.plot()
        plt.show()

selector.observe(multiplot, names='value')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, this is really cool! If you don't mind a follow-up question; Is it possible to make it so that **all** series are plotted when **none** are selected?

Comment: Sure. You can use a conditional to test for `if not choices:` (this would mean an empty tuple), and then set `data = df` in that conditional block. Your `else` condition should set `data = df.loc[:, choices]`.

Comment: I've already marked your suggestion as the accepted answer, but would you like to edit your answer to include your suggestion in your comment as well?

Comment: I tried your suggestion to plot all series when none are selected, but have failen on numerous attempts. I'd really appreaciate it if you could find the time to make a little edit in your answer.

Comment: Have added the conditional above.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't think it worked. I'm still just getting one series selected.

Comment: Don't know what to say, this works on Mac with Chrome and ipywidgets 7.4.2. Try printing `choices` in the function body to see what is happening.

Comment: Thats strange. I'm using the exact snippet you provided. When I restart the kernel, and run fresh start, there's no output. I **have** to make a selection in the widget to get a result. The only lines displayed are the ones that are selected. Upon a fresh start, nothing is printed. When clicking the widget, the name of the selection is printed.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You won't see any plot to start with as you haven't clicked on the widget yet. Try deselecting your choice once you have selected one, then you should see the three series plotted. Alternatively add `multiplot({'new': ()})` at the end of the code, but that is a bit of a hack.

Comment: De-selecting does in fact show all series! Your suggestions have been extremely useful to me! Would you consider moving our conversation to chat regarding a few details on the `You won't see any plot to start with as you haven't clicked on the widget yet` part?  I swear I won't bother you *too* much! A few minutes on monday perhaps? For now, have a splendid weekend!

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way I have found to use the `multipleSelect` widget is using the decorator `interact`.

```py
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets.widgets import interact, SelectMultiple

np.random.seed(123)
rows = 50
dfx = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(90,110,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable X'])
dfy = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(25,68,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable Y'])
dfz = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(60,70,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable Z'])

df = pd.concat([dfx,dfy,dfz], axis = 1)

sel_mul = SelectMultiple(description="Variables",options=df.columns,value=['Variable X','Variable Z'],disabled=False)
@interact(variables=sel_mul)
def plot_multiple(variables):
    df[list(variables)].plot()
```

And this is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6xuE.png).